# How to use Mockito for WebClient get call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito, webclient

I've been mainly working on Angular and frontend so far and just got into the world of Java Spring to enhance my backend skills. I need to implement the WebClient to do REST calls and was able to do the implementation but stuck on the test class. This is what I have so far:

...codeset/service/impl/CodesetService.java:

```
@Component
public class CodesetService {
    private final WebClient codesetClient;

    @Autowired
    public CodesetService (@Qualifier("codesetClient") final WebClient codesetClient, RestConfiguration restConfig) {
        this.codesetClient = codesetClient;
    }

    protected List<CodeAll> getCodeset(String codesetName, TracingInfo tracingInfo) {
        return codesetClient
                .get()
                .uri(builder -> builder.queryParam("codeset", codesetName).build())
                .headers(headers -> createHttpHeadersConsumer(tracingInfo))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(CodeAll.class)
                .collectList()
                .block();
    }
}
```

...codeset/rest/RestConfiguration.java:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration {
    private final String codesetServiceUrl;
    private final String codeAllPath;

    public RestConfiguration(
            @Value("${codeset-service.url}") String codesetServiceUrl,
            @Value("${codeset-service.codeAllPath}") String codeAllPath
    ) {
        this.codesetServiceUrl = codesetServiceUrl;
        this.codeAllPath = codeAllPath;
    }

    @Bean("codesetClient")
    public WebClient codesetClient() {
        final var builder =
                new WebClientBuilder(
                        codesetServiceUrl + codeAllPath,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        Optional.empty(),
                        Optional.empty());

        return builder.build();
    }

    public String getCodesetServiceUrl() {
        return codesetServiceUrl;
    }

    public String getCodeAllPath() {
        return codeAllPath;
    }
}
```

Does this look correct to you so far?

Then, in the test class, how to implement the WebClient mock using Mockito? See the comment in the code block.

...codeset/service/impl/CodesetServiceTest.java:

```
class CodesetServiceTest {
@Mock
WebClient codesetClient;

private List<CodeAll> createCodeList(String code) {
    return Collections.singletonList(
            CodeAll.builder().code(code).endDate(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)).build());
}

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    underTest =
            new CodesetService(
                    codesetClient, restConfig);
    when(restConfig.getCodesetServiceUrl()).thenReturn("getCodesetServiceUrl");
    when(restConfig.getCodeAllPath()).thenReturn("/getCodeAllPath");

    // Here, how to call the "getCodesetServiceUrl/getCodeAllPath?codeset=code-set-name" using Mockito?
    // Response type would be <List<CodeAll>> and return: createCodeList("code")
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's probably some bealdung somewhere on the internet.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your test never calls `underTest.getCodeset`, why? And what's your question about "how to implement the WebClient mock"?

Comment: That's what I'm here for. As I told, I'm a frontend developer. Something that may seem very obvious to you (as a Java Dev), is not obvious to me. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Where does `restConfig` in your test come from? Why is it not used by your implementation?